# How to print City name in corresponding cells

Tags: excel

[image]

I shown my data above.
In my data some cells may have some name's like `HYDERABAD` and `Secunderabad`. I want to print which cells have  `HYDERABAD` then print `HYDERABAD` corresponding Cell. How to do This Please let me know

Comment: Could you put how the result should look like in another picture in your question?

Comment: Ram, did you insert a new picture? There's only the first picture you initially had in your question :(

Comment: what is your doubt please tell me i will clarify?

Comment: I would like to know how your spreadsheet should look like after you get the solution, so that it's clear what you want to achieve. In the picture above, you have three columns. You have the first one already, and want to get all the cells that have `HYDERABAD`, meaning you want to get only the 4th row into a new cell?

Comment: i want to print `hyderabad ` in corresponding rows only @Jerry

Comment: Can I ask the purpose for this? Are you trying to count how many rows have `hyperabad`. Because, in the end, you will have a series of `hyperbad` printed, which doesn't look too useful to me, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list with all the cities in a range (in my example is W8:W10) then use this formula:

```
=INDEX($W$8:$W$10;SUMPRODUCT(1*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($W$8:$W$10;T1))*(ROW($W$8:$W$10)-ROW($W$8)+1)))
```

Values, in my case, start in T1 and down, formula in U1 and down

[image]

Comment: here what is meant by W8:W10?

Comment: It's the range containing all possible city names (in the example only 3 cities) But if, for example, you have 20 cities, write all those 20 city names in a range containing 20 cells like W1:W20. Then replace W8:W10 by W1:W20

Comment: We should mention the cities names in the formula?

Comment: No, you use a range for that, in the example is the range W8:W10 (with 3 city names) you need another range (a bigger one)

Comment: I added a picture with 3 city names in W8:W10